# Suggest consolidating the [measureoverride] and [arrangeoverride] tags (WPF-related)

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Tags [measureoverride](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/measureoverride) and [arrangeoverride](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrangeoverride) both refer to procedures in WPF programming that have to do with customizing [its layout system](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/layout) for an application.

Programming measuring & arranging logic is somewhat of an arcane detail. But in the WPF layout system measuring & arranging are by design always going to be used together. As such it doesn't really make sense to me to have individual tags for them.

Instead I propose consolidating them into a new tag called something like `wpf-layout-system`. That would be inclusive of these two plus offer a slightly broader catchment of related questions that would be useful to readers researching this area of WPF programming but can't be easily subdivided from the many 1000s of general `wpf-*` tagged questions.

They are each used right now on ~30 questions with some overlap between them. However I think there are probably a good number of additional questions which are actually about closely related topics that would fall into the proposed new `wpf-layout-system` tag.